# Hide the console of an .exe file created with PyInstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I want to make my program executable.
I used TkInter to write the GUI, and I read somewhere that you have to save your file as .pyw to hide the console when the program is executed.
The problem is that after making it an executable with PyInstaller, the console shows up again, even though the file converted was .pyw.
How can I hide the console also in the .exe file?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Did you try `--windowed` command line flag ?

Answer (score 4):

You can just save the file with .pyw extension and you can just use `pyinstaller --onefile Filename.pyw`
I think you renamed it. You save it as .pyw don't rename it.
The screenshot are below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Output:

[image]

But it takes a while to open.
Thank you
-Levers

Answer (score 3):

Rather than saving/renaming/changing the extension to `.pyw`, you can just add `--noconsole` to the command line and use the standard `.py` file with it and this would hide that console window.

**Example:**

We have a file named `GUI_name.py` in our folder that uses Tkinter. Now we could easily create `.exe` file that doesn't show the console window by typing `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole GUI_name.py` in cmd.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to make the executable?

If you use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and you use:

```
setup(windows=[pythonscriptnamehere])
```

in the setup script instead of:

```
setup(console=[pythonscriptnamehere])
```

it will run the executable without launching a terminal in the background.

Comment: I'm using PyInstaller, because I read that there isn't a version of py2exe for Python 3.5

Comment: Check out the pyinstaller documents:

Answer (score 1):

From The PyInstaller Documentation:

> Using a Console Window
>
> By default the bootloader creates a command-line console (a terminal
> window in GNU/Linux and Mac OS, a command window in Windows). It gives
> this window to the Python interpreter for its standard input and
> output. Your script’s use of print and input() are directed here.
> Error messages from Python and default logging output also appear in
> the console window.
>
> An option for Windows and Mac OS is to tell PyInstaller to not provide
> a console window. The bootloader starts Python with no target for
> standard output or input. Do this when your script has a graphical
> interface for user input and can properly report its own diagnostics.
>
> As noted in the CPython tutorial Appendix, for Windows a file
> extention of .pyw suppresses the console window that normally appears.
> Likewise, a console window will not be provided when using a
> myscript.pyw script with PyInstaller.