# How to convert a pyw file to exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe

How can I convert a ***pyw*** file to ***exe*** using pyinstaller and if its not possible how do i do it with py2exe ?

I am using ***python 3*** !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just run the following command

```
pyinstaller -w your_file_name.pyw
```

Note: you need to install pyinstaller before running the above command.To install, run the following command

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Comment: even with -w argument?

Comment: not getting an error but it just opens cmd and stays empty

Comment: with -w argument, it wont open a cmd

Comment: you can use -w or  --windowed or  --noconsole

Answer (score 3):

Because you use Python 3 it is not possible to use Py2exe (since that is for Python 2 only).

Rename your .pyw program to .py and run (provided you have installed Pyinstaller):

```
pyinstaller file.py
```

And use the `--windowed` flag [to hide the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129537/hide-the-console-of-an-exe-file-created-with-pyinstaller).

Comment: Py2exe now works with Python3