# Create executable without console from a .pyw file

Tags: python

I made a application that has to can run in background, so I made a script.pyw but I don't know how to make a executable that can do it .
can you please help me ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add your approaches, your code and say which errors you face. This is not a wishlist platform. Please also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a pyw file to exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427713/how-to-convert-a-pyw-file-to-exe)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyinstaller` to do so. First, install `pyinstaller`:

```
$ pip install pyinstaller
```

Then, run `pyinstaller`, passing the file to convert

```
$ pyinstaller script.pyw --onefile --windowed
```

Comment: Sorry but when I execute the script.exe, there is written "failled to execute" it may is because mi code need a module