# hide console with executing python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile my python script built in python 3 using pyqt5 module on windows 10 using pyinstaller which hides the windows while running.

To compile my script I executed following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=app.ico --clean --noconsole app.py
```

But the executable I got didn't worked so again I compiled my script by following command:

```
 pyinstaller --onefile -w --icon=app.ico  app.py
```

Still the output executable is not working if **--console/-w/--windowed** argument is used.

**How can I make my executable run without console?**

this is the script i try to execute it

```
import threading
import subprocess
import sys
import time

f = open("build\\eco.txt", "x")
f = open("build\\sou.txt", "x")

def run_process(path):
    cmd = 'python %s' % path
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
        sys.stdout.write(line)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_process, args=('py1.py',))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=run_process, args=('py2.py',))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=run_process, args=('py3.py',))
t4 = threading.Thread(target=run_process, args=('py4.py',))
t5 = threading.Thread(target=run_process, args=('py5.py',))


#start
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
t5.start()

# Waiting
t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()
t5.join()
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide the console of an .exe file created with PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129537/hide-the-console-of-an-exe-file-created-with-pyinstaller)

Comment: Not worked as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass **-w or --windowed or --noconsole** flag to hide console.

Try GUI pyinstaller by installing **auto py to exe**. It makes you more easier to compile your script.

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

Comment: i tried it as well but not working, it is using pyinstaller by the way

Comment: **-w or --windowed or --noconsole** works perfectly for me to hide console. Maybe reinstalling pyinstaller might solve your problem

Comment: yes, it works with pyqt5. And you have to include files like pictures, etc in one directory (in case you have not )