# Make an exe file not showing a terminal

Tags: python

I am using "auto py to exe" to create an exe file from my python script. It works quite well, but it opens a terminal once I launch the script... How can I make it to hide / not display the terminal, like a daemon or a back-process?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hide console with executing python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566381/hide-console-with-executing-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `--noconsole` argument in the "Manual Argument Input" section. Otherwise, the option to do this should be somewhere there as seen [here.](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)