# Pyinstaller hide terminal when running .exe

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, pyinstaller

I have a python script that I turned into an .exe file using Pyinstaller.

```
Pyinstaller --onefile API_app.py
```

This works fine and I can run my .exe file and it fully works.
However, when I run my file the terminal opens before opening the app. 
The terminal also remains open when running the app (and after closing the app) and I have to manually close it.

Is there a way I can run my file without the terminal opening so I just see my app? 
Also, the opening of the app seems really slow (opening takes 30 sec, which seems slow to me. it is a relatively small file with 75 lines of python code max.), is there a way to fasten this process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide the console of an .exe file created with PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129537/hide-the-console-of-an-exe-file-created-with-pyinstaller)

Comment: This does unfortunately not work. I still get the same folders. I now get 2 .exe files. one with terminal logo, this still works but also still shows the terminal.The other file is a floppy disk logo. I can run the latter one but this does not open my app.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the inbuilt argument

```
--noconsole
```

It will execute in the background with no no console